# Problem with Class, Filters and Callbacks

Tags: filters, callbacks

according to this [Callback example](https://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Callback) if I'm referencing a method inside a class, I should use add_filter by specifying an array with 2 elements, first the object then the method. Here is my code:

```
add_action ('login_head', array('Admin', 'plugin_setup'));

class Admin 
{
   public function plugin_setup()
   {
      add_filter('login_headerurl', array($this, 'the_logo_url'));   
   }

   private function the_logo_url()
   {
      return get_bloginfo('url');
   }
```

unfortunately my code does not seem to work unless I move the function `the_logo_url()` outside the class. What's the best way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Change `private` to `public` and make `plugin_setup()` static.

Comment: @birgire: I get yet the following msg error `PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code snippet:

```
add_action( 'login_head', [ 'WPSE_Admin', 'plugin_setup' ] );

class WPSE_Admin 
{
   public static function plugin_setup()
   {
      add_filter( 'login_headerurl', [ 'WPSE_Admin', 'the_logo_url' ] );   
   }

   public function the_logo_url()
   {
      return get_bloginfo('url');
   }
}
```

The filter callbacks must be *public*, not *private*. The reason for this is that  `apply_filters()/apply_filters_ref_array()` are running `call_user_func_array()` on the stored filter callbacks, in the global `$wp_filter` array.

Also notice that you're not instantiating your `WPSE_Admin` class, so you can't use `$this`. You might want to use *namespace* but I just prefix the class here.